# How to lock formula range from changing if table changes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, if I am working with a table that is linked to an Access query that is constantly being updated and changes from 40 cells in length to 60  back to 10 cells:

I would like the formula cell range to stay at a consistent A:1 to A:100 range.

**The following is the formula I am working with:**

```
=(CONCATENATE(TEXT(MIN(Tab1!D1:D100),"M/DD/YY")," 
- ",TEXT(MAX(Tab1!D1:D100),"M/DD/YY")))
```

Currently, when updating this table the range keeps shifting along with the length of the table, how can the formula range be locked

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with your formula? Just a title of the date range? If the cells update from the table and those original 100 rows are re-positioned, does this effect your question at all? What is the reason to keep the references exact, so we have a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I guess JvdV has already provided you the answer. I would like to suggest you to consider another possibility of using `#powerquery` which allows you to import the query from Access to Excel Power Query Editor, and you can find the minimum and maximum time from the query and concatenate them in the editor and load the output which would be a text string to the desired location of your worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Lock your cells like so:

`=(CONCATENATE(TEXT(MIN(Tab1!$D$1:$D$100),"M/DD/YY")," - ",TEXT(MAX(Tab1!$D$1:$D$100),"M/DD/YY")))`

By surrounding the cell references in "$" it won't resize or move as you drag the formula around.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. If `Tab1!D1:D100` is actually an access table that grows or shrinks the reference in this formula wille change. No matter absolute references.

Comment: @JvdV you are correct, double checked this and you're absolutely right. Locking the cells will make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If your formula is referencing a table (an actual table) without using the table column name (e.g. `=max(Tabel1[Test])`), your `Tab1!D1:D100` reference will increase/decrease no matter if you use absolute or relative cell references.

So the correct way for you would be to reference the actual table column, OR if you really only want to know up to row 100 (even if the table grows beyond a 100 lines) you can use `INDEX` to reference a particular range of cells, e.g.: `...(Tab1!$D$1:INDEX(Tab1!$D:$D,100))...`

---

**Example**

- Some small table to work with:

[image]

- Formula in another tab:

  ```
  =MAX(Tab1!$D$1:$D$11)
  ```
- Now drag the table in Tab1 a few rows down and you'll notice the formula has changed, e.g. 4 rows would result in:

  ```
  =MAX(Tab1!$D$1:$D$15)
  ```
- To prevent this you could either reference the table column, e.g:

  ```
  =MAX(Tabel1[Test])
  ```
- Or if you don't want to get values when the table grows beyond 100 rows, use `INDEX` to "lock" the range in, e.g:

  ```
  =MAX(Tab1!$D$1:INDEX(Tab1!$D:$D,100))
  ```

Comment: If the table updates, we need to ensure the first 100 rows are the same, no? I'd imagine the OP wants the original 100 cells, because of what they hold, so if the table updates and these cells are repositioned it wouldn't matter if the formula is the same. We should clarify this question with @Jamie Mills first.

Comment: @MarkS. The way I read the question is the range grows/shrinks having an effect on the formula used. I assume OP looks for a max # of rows of 100 and no further (while less is fine). But it's always good to get some clarification :)

Comment: Based on the formula, it seems like the want to display a date range of the data being shown in the table. So from that I figure they may want their formula, but when the table resizes it hasn't properly resized with it so they want to go to row 100, just to make sure the table is always captured. If that's the case, the named references would be great for this. Your second to last formula won't prevent resizing though like your comment implied.